# Trying to use MvvmCross attribute MvxUnconventionalViewAttribute

Tags: view, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am trying to use the MvxUnconventionalViewAttribute in MvvmCross v3.5. It seems I am missing a library as it does not compile.

The type or namespacename 'MvxUnconventionalViewAttribute could not be found

Here's an example of what I am trying

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views

namespace X
{
     [MvxUnconventionalView]
     public class MyView : MvxViewController
     {
          ...
     }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what nuget packages I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the Attribute is `MvxUnconventionalAttribute` not MvxUnconventional**View**Attribute and it's in the namespace `Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC`.

See: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Platform/Platform/IoC/MvxUnconventionalAttribute.cs

Comment: Or the namespace is `MvvmCross.Platform.IoC` on 4.0